# How to enable ssh on raspberry without screen?

Tags: ssh

my problem is, that I do not have screen and keyboard on raspberry. And I am trying to connect to it via SSH. But from default is in sshd_config set: PubkeyAuthentication to yes. And that is my problem, because when I copy .img file to SD card I`m unable to login via ssh because of pubkeyauthentication. How can I change it to no using my PC? (Ubuntu) I tried to mount .img file and edit sshd_config, but I am able to mount it only read-only. What do u suggest?

Comment: Have you attempted editing the `sshd_config` file as sudo?

Comment: You should be able to mount the SD card on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to login with a password? Then I think it's the PasswordAuthentication option you want to check. It doesn't matter if PubkeyAuthentication is yes as well, they can both be yes. Add the -v option to get debug info during connection setup: ssh -v user@rpi